# how can i use a grid view in to another grid view

Tags: asp.net-2.0

i want to use a grid view into the row of a grid view can i use it? any ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some good tutorials for you:

- [Gridview Inside a GridView in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/GridViewInsideGridView.aspx)
- [Build a Nested GridView Control with ASP.NET](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3633561/Build-a-Nested-GridView-Control-with-ASPNET.htm)